# Problem with loading new emails on Mail

Tags: mail.app

Something started happening to one of my mail accounts on Mail one of these days.
When I press Get New Mail, it starts downloading, showing the KB/s of the Mail Activity.
The problem is, without even downloading the first new email, the KB/s starts dropping to 0 and no emails are downloaded... This only happens to this email account and has been happening for some days now.
Any ideas of what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting Mail, or maybe your computer? Sounds dumb, but it’s amazing how often it works.

Comment: Yes I have... No luck. It starts downloading, but fast the KB/s starts dropping until it reaches 0 KB/s and then no emails are downloaded.

Comment: Have you got another email account and does this work - if not get another free one and try - e.g. gmail fastmail etc.

Comment: Yes, I have 3 other accounts from Gmail and they're working fine...

Comment: I had this problem before with my gmail account and can't fix it, also read somewhere that it was a bug for mail.app so I switch to thunderbird and this software really satisfy me.

Comment: Can you load Console.app and check to see if there are any Mail error messages (you'll need to click 'All Messages' in Console).

Comment: Yes, I got this `12/2/10 10:19:18 AM Mail[22020] -[POP3Connection fetchMessages:totalBytes:] failed: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=54 UserInfo=0x1153e0d90 "The attempt to send data to the server “(null)” failed."`

Answer (score 1):

Try using Cmd-0 to bring up the more detailed Activity Window within mail. I've often been able to track down mail problems by looking in there.

Answer (score 0):

right clicking the account in mailbox section of the left panel in Mail and clicking 'get account info' could help to see if it's connecting to the mailbox properly.

You could also try turning it off and on again - ie. right click account again then click 'take "[account name]" offline' and then repeating to 'take "[account name]" online' may help...

Failing that, see if you can connect to that account through a webmail client - if you have one available for that account to see if it's a problem with the email server rather than mail.